# PhpUnit code coverage html report is not getting created

Tags: php, phpunit, php-code-coverage

I am running below command to create code coverage in html form

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --whitelist --coverage-html tests
```

It is running but not creating code coverage report.
[image]

Comment: Think about what information a person might need to answer this question and edit your post to include it. We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug is probably not installed. Run `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug` and try again.